# PHP how to implement reading a file conitnously and update UI via AJAX call

Tags: php

I am a novice in PHP and need to implement coding for following scenario.

The Web page would make a AJAX call to a PHP script at backend. The PHP script is suppose to read a file / data at serial port continuously which is having some values. So the UI should check if there is a updated value and update it as received via response from PHP script thru AJAX call made.

But the issue I am facing is the PHP script has to open the file /serial port only once and keep reading but also to service the UI AJAX call.

As such how in same PHP script it would keep reading file / serial port continuously and service the UI AJAX call (the read data from file should be not read again).

Comment: PHP doesn't run continuously. It runs then finishes, otherwise you don't get a response from the script. You need to design it to run the script on request.

Comment: with "the read data from file should be not read again" you mean no other user/browser/service should be able to read the same file as well?

Comment: Well the data once read should not be read again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a permanent connection between client/browser and server using [elephant.io](http://elephant.io/), but i wouldn't recommend it. So this leaves two other options:

1. switching to node.js for just this one task since that would make it
   faily easy using socket.io to have a socket connection between
   browser/server and thus informing on file changes.
2. just regularly check via a tiny ajax call if the last-touched timestamp of the file has changed and if so, use a second ajax query to pull the changes.